# SF Communities: How can I modify the page layout on the "My Account" page from the User Profile menu?

Tags: customer-community

I can't figure out where/how to edit this layout. I can create a new Account detail community page but that's not the layout that displays when somebody clicks 'My Account' from the User Profile menu. Where is this layout set and how can I edit it? If it's not editable for some reason is there a workaround like cloning, modifying, and redirecting the menu link to the cloned page?

Comment: Under template pages, you will find "Account Management". You can or i think should be able to modify this page

Comment: @Raj yes I can edit that page, but that is not the page that displays when I am logged into the community and I click the dropdown arrow to the right of my username at top right of page (the User Profile menu) and choose 'My Account' -- there is some other Account Detail layout specific to this menu item and I can't figure out where or how to edit it.

Comment: It looks like the layout is the default Record Detail page, which I can edit, but I don't know how I change which fields are visible on that page. Obviously the field list is different for different object types so this must be set somewhere else. Do I need to set this outside the community builder?

Comment: It looks like the layout is the default Record Detail page, which I can edit, but I don't know how I change which fields are visible on that page. Obviously the field list is different for different object types so this must be set somewhere else. Do I need to set this outside the community builder?

Comment: You can create a new page variation with choice of your page type or create a lightning component and drop it in the content area. I mean i dont know how else you can edit the actual layout. Good luck